# clarification for css nth-child() and nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to assign different background-image for each of 10 elements with `employee` class. the hierarchy of the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="crew-row">
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
</div>
<div class="crew-row">
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
</div>
<div class="crew-row">
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>
</div>
```

so i thought i can use something like this in my css:

```css
employee:nth-of-type(1){
    background-image: url('../images/people/1.png');
}
.employee:nth-of-type(2){
    background-image: url('../images/people/2.png');
}
.employee:nth-of-type(3){
    background-image: url('../images/people/3.png');

}
.employee:nth-of-type(4){
    background-image: url('../images/people/4.png');
}
.employee:nth-of-type(5){
    background-image: url('../images/people/5.png');

}
...
```

or

```css
.employee:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url('../images/people/1.png');
}
.employee:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url('../images/people/2.png');
}
.employee:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url('../images/people/3.png');

}
.employee:nth-child(4){
    background-image: url('../images/people/4.png');
}
.employee:nth-child(5){
    background-image: url('../images/people/5.png');

}
...
```

but what happens is that even before i add any further code for the rest of `employee` they already assigned with previous background images...
any idea what will be the correct way to assign different `background-image` to each  the `employee` elements?

Comment: You can not do this with just CSS

Comment: `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` selector only works for elements that are directly under **the same parent**. In your example `.employee`s don't share the same parent, thus not work with your CSS rule.

Comment: ***Neither of the two pseudo-selectors cares about css classes at all.*** One just cares about element type (`:nth-of-type`) under the same parent element, the other just asks "Am I the `:nth-child` of my parent?". No more, no less. In both cases, you will need to get rid of your wrapping `div`s (which probably aren't necessary anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:nth-*` pseudo class match elements based on their nth position with respect to their parent, not the entire document. So you can do this:

```
.crew-row:nth-child(1) .employee:nth-child(1) { }
.crew-row:nth-child(1) .employee:nth-child(2) { }

.crew-row:nth-child(2) .employee:nth-child(1) { }
.crew-row:nth-child(2) .employee:nth-child(2) { }
.crew-row:nth-child(2) .employee:nth-child(3) { }
.crew-row:nth-child(2) .employee:nth-child(4) { }

/* and so on */
```

However, I would rather get rid of `.crew-row` elements (they do not seem so serve a purpose other than grouping employees in separate rows) and use `:nth-child` to (i) assign background images (ii) push the 3rd, 7th, 11th, ... employee on to a new row.

Answer (score 0):

```
employee:nth-of-type(1){
    background-image: url('../images/people/1.png');
}
```

In above code, `employee:nth-of-type(1)` specify a background for every `<div>` element with class name `employee` which is the first child of its parent.

So, with above code background of following `div` will be changed.
[image]

This is because all red marked `div` is the first child of it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a much better idea to add separate classes like `.employee-1` `.employee-2` and so on. `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` only work when the elements are direct siblings of each other. So in your case they are wrapped in `.crew-row` and therefore `nth-child(1)` will select the first employee in each row...

The difference between `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` is simply that `nth-of-type` selects number n of a specific type. E.g.

```
<div class="crew-row">
    <span class="employee"></span>
    <div class="employee"></div>
    <div class="employee"></div>  <!-- trying to select this one -->
</div>


div:nth-child(2) {  } /* Not working */
div:nth-of-type(2) {  } /* Working */
```

If you still want to work with `nth-child` you can do it like this:

```
.crew-row:nth-child(1) .employee:nth-child(1) {} /* select first employee in first row */
.crew-row:nth-child(1) .employee:nth-child(2) {} /* select second employee in first row */
.crew-row:nth-child(2) .employee:nth-child(1) {} /* select first employee in second row */
/* and so on */
```

but again, probably better to just add classes .employee-[n] and assign backgrounds to these classes

```
<div class="employee employee-1"></div>
.employee.employee-1{
    background-image: url('../images/people/1.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use jquery's "each" function

```js
$('.employee').each(function(index) {
  var i = index % 5;
  if (i == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
  } else if (i == 1) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#00ff00");
  } else if (i == 2) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#0000ff");
  } else if (i == 3) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffff00");
  } else if (i == 4) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#00ffff");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crew-row">
  <div class="employee">1</div>
  <div class="employee">2</div>
</div>
<div class="crew-row">
  <div class="employee">3</div>
  <div class="employee">4</div>
  <div class="employee">5</div>
  <div class="employee">6</div>
</div>
<div class="crew-row">
  <div class="employee">7</div>
  <div class="employee">8</div>
  <div class="employee">9</div>
  <div class="employee">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could combine html5, css and js to get that effect. you could stack them (html5 allows multiple background images stacked on top of each other) and using javascript or jquery - loop through each div and change the z-index of the stacked images. Or tie it to the scroll event and when the user scrolls past a certain poin, trigger the z-index change so that the next div has the modified background image.

Comment: why the down vote? this is one alternative to achieve the outcome. It may not be as sexy as others, but it is certainly viable as an alternative. and it is valid html to layer background images.

Comment: I think its because this is possible to do with css alone, yet this answer states it isn't?

Comment: Answer amended thank you. I have done some funky transitions, animations and pseudo parallax scrolling by layering background images and then moving them aroud.